# How many 9-digit numbers are there with an even digit sum?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many 9-digit numbers are there with an even digit sum?

How do I approach this task? I know the answer, but want to see how I need to think about solving it.

My approach to solving this was very long, mechanical and error-prone.

I noticed that the number of odd digits has to be even. And considered these scenarios:

1. 0 odd numbers, 9 even numbers
2. 2 odd numbers, 7 even numbers
3. 4 odd numbers, 5 even numbers
4. 6 odd numbers, 3 even numbers
5. 8 odd numbers, 1 even number

Then I considered 2 more cases:

1. The number can start with an odd digit.
2. The number can start with an even digit.

This amounts to this:

1. $4\times 5^8$
2. $5^9\times {8 \choose 1} + 4\times 5^8\times {8 \choose 6}$
3. $5^9\times {8\choose 3}+4\times5^8\times{8\choose 4}$
4. $5^9\times {8\choose 5}+4\times5^8\times{8\choose 2}$
5. $5^9\times {8\choose 7}+4\times5^8\times{8\choose 0}$

After I added them up I got $9\times 5\times 10^7$.

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: The first digit can be any digit but zero. The next seven digits can be any digit. The last digit must match the parity of the sum of the first eight digits.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thanks!

Comment: your number has to have an even number of odd digits, then you have to allow for the number not having leading zeroes, then it is some sort of permutation, combinations exercise - could be approached different ways - how about starting with hown many are there of format 1XXXXXXXX etc

Comment: @Cato the sum of digits must be even.

Comment: @Cato your approach is extremely error prone.

Comment: @coder-man the idea is not to make errors.  I was only trying to help think of pointers towards solving it.  The best answer I've seen here in my opinion is the one about the final digit being a parity digit - I didn't think of that though

Comment: you got the same answer as me though - as per general reasoning in other answers, half of numbers have the property, but there are 900million 9 digit numbers (numbers 100,000,000 to 999,999,999 inclusive) leaving 450million to have the property

Comment: @Cato honestly. It is not right away obvious that half the numbers have this property, can you prove it?

Comment: @Coder-man - no I don't think it is obvious in a rigorous sense either.  Especially with the skew on the first digit, making it more likely to be an odd.

Comment: @Coder-man - it's possible to use an inductive argument I think, starting from 2 digit numbers, the first digit can then be combined with 5 digits to make 45 'even' and 45 'odd' property values, and henceforth for 3,4,5... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course just half of all 9-digit numbers!

To see this, think of just the last digit: since half of those are odd and half are even, that means that whatever sum you have for all the digits preceding it, half will be made even by adding the last digit, and half will be made odd.

OK, and how many 9-digit numbers are there?

Well, the first digit is 1 of 9, and for the others you have 10 choices each. Hence:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot 9\cdot 10^8$$

Answer (score 1):

so you've got 4 different even digits you could start with, then you require 1,3,5,7 of any of the 5 evens

so that would be

$4 \times 5 \times 5^7 \times {8\choose 1} + 4 \times 5^3 \times 5^5 \times {8\choose 3} + 4 \times 5^5 \times 5^3 \times {8\choose 5} + 4 \times 5^7 \times 5 \times {8\choose 7}$

= 12500000 + 87500000 + 87500000 +12500000 = 200000000 - or 2oo million

then for starting with the 5 odd digits is

$5 \times (5^8 + 5^2 \times 5^6 * {8 \choose 2} + 5^4 \times 5^4 * {8 \choose 4} + 5^2 \times 5^6 * {8 \choose 6} + 5^8 \times 5^0 * {8 \choose 0} )$

=250000000

so there are 200 million starting with even digits and 250 million making a total of 450million

I included this for completeness, it's obviously not the simplest solution, it was  what I was talking about earlier

Comment: Thanks! Yea, this is exactly how I was thinking, but I think it's easy to make a mistake with this reasoning! (at least for me, because I'm bad at memorizing many things).